# How to enable CORS from within CircleCI to support automated testing

Tags: cors, automated-tests, circleci

Recently I started to run into problems with CORS, as many had the pleasure before me. I was able to fix the issue for my local environment using the following setups. Currently, the app is still in development so I know I probably should limit the CORS Origins before releasing the application.

**CORS-middleware**

```
    /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    //ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
    ];

    if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS"){
        //The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return response()->json('OK',200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
        $response->header($key, $value);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

**Kernel**

```
protected $middleware = [
    //Other middlewares
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

This resolved the issue I was facing with CORS in my local environment(homestead). Unfortunately, now my tests are failing within CircleCI. So the question is how could I enable the CORS stuff so that my tests are running again.

**Example test**

```
public function test_we_can_retrieve_all_places() {
    $response = $this->get('api/places');
    $response
        ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

**Test output:**
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else might be encountering the error mentioned above, the steps below helped me resolve my problem.

First I added `dd($respone)` within my test that outputted quite a lot of stuff that wasn't too useful. But it will dump possible exceptions as well. One of the exceptions I was able to discover was the one below.

```
Laravel phpunit Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

And what I did to resolve it is adjusted the bit of code above to the following:

```
//ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
$headers = [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
];
```

And this resolved my error